# python using selenium to send spacebar to scroll and beautiful soup to parse html

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
browser.get("https://steamcommunity.com/app/933110/reviews/?browsefilter=toprated&snr=1_5_100010_")
    url = browser.current_url
    page = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
    actions = ActionChains(browser)

    for y in range(50):
        for x in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "apphub_CardTextContent"}):
            print(x.text.strip() + "\n")
            actions.send_keys(Keys.SPACE).perform()
            time.sleep(1)
```

I am trying to get the text of every review of this game on the Steam store. There are over 2000 reviews. The function I attempted to write will get the same reviews that are within the parsing area of what is loaded but the 1900 other reviews are not being printed. I need the code to scroll down and get every review. I used 50 as a test but unsure how many space bars I will need to get to the bottom of the page. The main problem is that when I print the HTML using prettify() the HTML doesn't show every review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re: scrolling to the bottom of the page consistently, I've found it's easiest to use `execute_script` and let javascript do that for you. That would look like this in your example:

> `browser.execute_script("scroll(0, document.body.parentNode.scrollHeight)")`

Re: not seeing all of the claims, I think the problem is that you define `soup` before your loop. I believe this means that when you call `soup.find_all()` inside the loop, you only ever parse that initial page you obtained with `page = requests.get(url).text`. Since Selenium and Beautiful Soup aren't connected, you'll have to make a new request for every new section of reviews in order to load the response into `soup` and parse from there.

If you want to go the Selenium route, you could do the scrolling and get the text from the elements using selenium's methods: `browser.find_elements_by_class_name("apphub_CardTextContent")`, and then get the text when you're looping with `element.get_attribute("innerText")`

I would lean more towards just using `requests` to get the html documents and parse with Beautiful Soup, just because that means less DOM interaction, which usually means fewer bugs (in my experience). However, from looking at the site, it seems like you might have to dig in to replicating their requests for the html of the extra reviews.

Answer (score 0):

try this code with requests and BS4

```
import selenium
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

for i in range (0,10):
    url = "https://steamcommunity.com/app/933110/homecontent/?userreviewscursor=AoIIPwcQI3XbjqgC&userreviewsoffset={0}&p={1}&workshopitemspage={1}&readytouseitemspage={1}&mtxitemspage={1}&itemspage={1}&screenshotspage={1}&videospage={1}&artpage={1}&allguidepage={1}&webguidepage={1}&integratedguidepage={1}&discussionspage={1}&numperpage={1}&browsefilter=toprated&browsefilter=toprated&appid=933110&appHubSubSection=10&appHubSubSection=10&l=english&filterLanguage=default&searchText=&forceanon=1".format(i*10,i+1)
    payload = {}
    headers= {}
    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data = payload)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text.encode('utf8'),features="html.parser")
    for x in soup.find_all("div", {"class": "apphub_CardTextContent"}):
        print(x.text.strip() + "\n")
```

Change range value accordingly, for range (1,10) first 10 pages posts will be displayed.

Comment: Tried this code and it kept printing the same 10 reviews but wouldnt get the other reviews